# HAproxy not caching credentials

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, amazon-elb

I have basic auth setup on haproxy as such:

```
frontend http
    bind *:80
    log global
    option httplog

    acl AuthOK http_auth(CCusers)
    http-request auth realm Arealm if !AuthOK

    acl backend_acl path_beg /api 
    use_backend django if backend_acl

    acl wordpress_acl path_beg /wp-admin /wp-login 
    use_backend wordpress if wordpress_acl

    default_backend react

userlist CCusers
  user billy insecure-password billy
```

It works for the most part, however when I load a page from my react frontend, all the subsequent api calls also require basic auth. I would have thought the credentials were cached by the browser for subsequent requests. I do have an AWS load balancer in front of this, which may be causing some issue?